# Image Control not displaying in Win Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm familiar with C#, but this is my first Windows Phone application so I don't really know what I'm doing. I have a few images (I assume this is the picturebox equivalent from form applications?) on my designer, but when I run it in the emulator they do not show up.

Here is my code:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Height= "14" Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment = "Top" Width = "14" Source="/Resources/Blackbox.png" Visibility = "Visible"/>
```

I'm probably missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your picture's URL is correct, also make sure that the Build action of your image is "Content". If the Build Action is Resource, then you must change your URL pattern to the following format:

```
/HostAssemblyName;component/UrlToYourImage
```

Content is much more better in terms of performance compared to Resource.