# Windows Phone 8.1 not displaying images with an image tag

Tags: image, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I'm currently using an `<image src="<full path to image>" />` tag in my MainPage.XAML. This is the first thing I'm trying to play around with when developing for Windows Phone. The image will show up in the designer, but when I debug the device (using a Lumia Icon running Windows Phone 8.1 Preview or any of the Emulators) the image won't show up. All I get is a blank screen.

All of the research I've done says that this should be as simple as using an image tag with a source attribute pointing at my picture. Am I missing something? Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind posting the xaml code you are actually using, so I can take a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could edit you question with the actual xaml code you are using so I could confirm that would be great, but from the reply you gave to @Kulasangar, I would suggest that your problem is that the file path you are giving is on your desktop. The phone/emulator will not have access to this file. You need to add the image into your Windows Phone project and change the src to be a relative path from the root of the solution.

You can add a file into the WP8 project simply by navigating to the file in a windows explorer and then dragging on dropping the file (image in this case) into the solution explorer tab in Visual Studio.

If you put the image directly into your projects root directory and not a sub fodler, your image tag in xaml should then look something like:

```
<Image Source="/Lockscreen.jpg" />
```

Comment: I had high hopes for this and changed my XAML from `<Image Source="C:\Sandbox\Lockscreen.jpg" />` to `<Image Source="\Assets\Lockscreen.jpg" />` (and I moved the actual image to the project's assets directory) but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I didn't read you post closely enough. Moving the picture to the correct directory wasn't enough. I needed to also add the picture to the folder as an existing item within the solution explorer for my phone to recognize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you closed the `Image` tag after :

```
<image src="<full path to image>">
```

and make sure that you give the correct path.

Should be something like this:

```
<Image Source="the path" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm using '<Image Source="C:\Sandbox\Lockscreen.jpg" />' and I can see the 'Lockscreen.jpg' image in the designer within Visual Studio, but not on my device while debugging.

Comment: This might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662367/image-control-not-displaying-in-win-phone-8-emulator